# Query optimization in query that uses many outer joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for ways to optimize the following SQL query. I'm using MS SQL Server 2008. I'm thinking if there's any way to consolidate the outer joins it would speed things up...If anyone has any input, it would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
SELECT employee.employee_id,
   coalesce (room.ship_id, ship.ship_id) AS ship_id,
   SUBSTRING (employee.service_id, 0, 6) AS cost_code,
   employee_station.room_cat AS nws_room_cat
FROM employee
   LEFT OUTER JOIN room
      ON     employee.ship_id = room.ship_id
         AND employee.floor_id = room.floor_id
         AND employee.room_id = room.room_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ship
      ON employee.ship_id = ship.ship_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_station
      ON COALESCE (ship.property_type, '') =
            COALESCE (employee_station.property_type, '')
         AND COALESCE (room.work_center_id, '') = COALESCE (employee_station.work_center_id, '')
         AND COALESCE (employee.pay_plan, '') =
                COALESCE (employee_station.pay_plan, '')
         AND COALESCE (employee.employee_type, '') =
                COALESCE (employee_station.employee_type, '')
         AND COALESCE (SUBSTRING (employee.service_id, 0, 6), '') =
                COALESCE (employee_station.cost_code, '')
   LEFT OUTER JOIN roomtype
      ON room.room_type = roomtype.room_type
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dp
      ON employee.service_id = dp.service_id
```

Note: I purposely left out a lot of the fields in the SELECT statement here for clarity purposes. So the roomtype and dp tables are actually being used...

Comment: Why the LEFT JOINs to tables `roomtype` and `dp`?  They are not doing anything here.

Comment: @BobDuell : Good spot, I was just about to ask the same question.

Comment: Oh actually there are a lot more fields that are part of the SELECT..however I excluded them here for clarity purposes...just makes it more concise. So those tables actually are needed because data is being pulled from them....I just didn't include the actual fields here.

Answer (score 1):

The OUTER JOINs aren't the problem. The problem is in wrapping columns inside functions.

```
ON COALESCE (ship.property_type, '') = COALESCE (employee_station.property_type, '')
```

This sort of construction prevents the optimizer from making an efficient query plan - it doesn't know what the value of the function will be until run time, and so it is unable to use indexes should they exist.

Rewrite the query without the functions and the optimizer will be able to make much better decisions.

Comment: How do you suggest I rewrite the query without the COALESCE functions? I think I would get very different results if I remove those functions...

Comment: The question is, why do you think they are necessary?  I don't use sql-server myself, but do the tables you are joining to actually have rows with a value expressed as ''?

Comment: @dido `ON ship.property_type = employee_station.property_type OR (ship.property_type IS NULL AND employee_station.property_type IS NULL)` or `ON EXISTS (SELECT employee_station.property_type INTERSECT SELECT ship.property_type)` see [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx)

Comment: Bob - they probably have a lot of NULL data. Dido - there is no magic solution. If it were my code, I think the first thing I'd try was extracting data to #temp tables and cleaning it up before joining, say replacing NULL with some sort of value. This can get complex.  The best thing, of course, is not to allow designs where any sort of key value can be NULL, but we often inherit them.

Comment: Hmmm so you're saying that we should re-structure the tables and maybe create a stored proc that would replace the NULLs with a value so that I can do away with the COALESCE functions? It's an idea but not sure if management will agree with that...

Comment: It was only a suggestion - when working with large sets of data in the past I have had good results with pulling data into #temp tables and either creating some kind of hash, or replacing NULLs in the #temp table before joining. As I said, this can be complex and is usually time-consuming. However, if your query demands it, you either have to do the work, or live with the existing performance.

Comment: @Martin Smith - i tried your solution but the query appears to run slower when i compare the query cost (relative to batch) in the execution plan

Answer (score 0):

You can try to join on CHECKSUMS - from my experience it often gives better performance than complicated condition:

```
SELECT 
--columns you need
FROM employee
LEFT OUTER JOIN room
ON CHECKSUM(employee.ship_id, employee.floor_id, employee.room_id) 
= CHECKSUM(room.ship_id, room.floor_id, room.room_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ship
ON employee.ship_id = ship.ship_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_station
ON CHECKSUM(ship.property_type, room.work_center_id, employee.pay_plan, employee.employee_type, SUBSTRING (employee.service_id, 0, 6)) 
= CHECKSUM(employee_station.property_type, employee_station.work_center_id, employee_station.pay_plan, employee_station.employee_type, employee_station.cost_code)
LEFT OUTER JOIN roomtype
ON room.room_type = roomtype.room_type
LEFT OUTER JOIN dp
ON employee.service_id = dp.service_id
```

Comment: ... last but not least: why room nor employee_station tables do not not have employee_id reference? -- it would make your query simpler and faster

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is deprecated it also won't work. ["SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)